# pass 2 values from one to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am very new to android.
i m trying to develop a login form for practise , and i m unable to pass and display 2 values
to another activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Success.class);
        EditText edituser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userinput);
        EditText editpass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passinput);
        String username = edituser.getText().toString();
        String password = editpass.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USER, username);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PASSWORD, password);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and target activity is

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_USER);
    String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PASSWORD);

    // Create the text view
    TextView userView = new TextView(this);
    TextView passView = new TextView(this);
    userView.setTextSize(40);
    userView.setText(username);

    passView.setTextSize(40);
    passView.setText(password);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(userView);
    setContentView(passView);
```

Comment: what is your problem with this code..

Comment: More specifically, what makes you unable to pass it?

Comment: i m only getting second value on screen ie. password,

Comment: Why setting the view twice??

Comment: setContentView(passView); causes it. I think you should use xml file with 2 textviews inside. it. findviewbyid of them, and set texts in both

Comment: how to print both values , to next display screen

Comment: don't `setContentView` twice. put them in a layout or use xml

Comment: you can use xml layout no simply..

Comment: place userView and passView in a single View...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `setContentView()` the second time, you remove the older view from the screen.

Try adding your Views to a ViewGroup like  a LinearLayout and then adding that to the screen instead of individual Views.

Something like:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.addView(userView);
ll.addView(passView);
setContentView(ll);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the second value only, because you are setting your view twice..
the second one overrides the username..

You can use `addContentView` instead, or create an xml that contains 2 text views and use that..

Answer (score 1):

use another layout and set intent values in the second layout....

```
setContentView(R.layout.anotherlayout);

TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.usertext);
TextView pass= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passtext);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_USER);
String password = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_PASSWORD);

user.setText(username);
pass.setText(password);
```